# Regular expression to discard "

Tags: regex

I have the next regular expression: `/i18n(-?).*="(.*)"/g` for javascript.

I use https://www.regextester.com to check.

```
<button i18n="@@user.button" data-test="download-confirmation_ok">
<a i18n-href="@@link.url" href="https://www.aaaa.es" target="_blank">
<div i18n="@@link.text">www.aaaa.es</div>
```

I don't like `data-test="download-confirmation_ok"` and `href="https://www.aaaa.es" target="_blank"`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmm0K.jpg

I only want i18n or i18n-* text between "TEXT".

How can I discard rest of the tetx?

Thank.

Comment: so what is the text you want to capture here? "www.aaaa.es"?

Comment: You might looking for something like this: https://regex101.com/r/qBhkPM/2.

Comment: I like this too  -->  i18n(-?)(.*?)=\"([^"]*)\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using simply:

```
/i18n\S+/g
```

It appears you only want the substring untill next space character, check [this](https://regex101.com/r/zm47Ea/3). This would however discard the last closing `>` at the first two strings.

Or if you want to grab text untill second `"` then maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/WQ7xiI/5):

```
/i18n[^"]+"[^"]+"/g
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(?<=i18n[^=]*?=([\'\"])).*?(?=\1)
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/zm47Ea/2)**

## Explanation:

I'm using a positive lookbehind here, which you can learn more about [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thank but lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript. Maybe I can use

i18n[^=]*?=([\'\"]).*?(?=\1)

Thank.

Comment: Yeah you can but you'll have to use the capturing group 2 to get the text in between. My mistake, I should've remembered that about Javascript.

Comment: So, what is the correct regular expression for javascript finally?
Thank.

Comment: I like this too  -->  i18n(-?)(.*?)="([^"]*)"

Answer (score 0):

HTML should really never be processed with regular expressions for a host of reasons. If I understand correctly that you only wish to keep attributes that begin with `i18n` or `i18n-`, then use a `DOMParser`:

```js
let html = `<button i18n="@@user.button" data-test="download-confirmation_ok">
<a i18n-href="@@link.url" href="https://www.aaaa.es" target="_blank">
<div i18n="@@link.text">www.aaaa.es</div>`;

let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
var allTags = doc.querySelectorAll("*");
for (let i = 0; i < allTags.length; i++) {
    let aTag = allTags[i];
    for (let j = aTag.attributes.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        let name = aTag.attributes[j].name;
        if (!/^i18n-?/.test(name)) {
            aTag.removeAttribute(name);
        }
    }
}
html = doc.body.innerHTML;
console.log(html);
```